# What will Taiwan's NSPO put in orbit around the Moon in 2025? How will it get there? What will it do?

Tags: space-telescope, smallsat, formosat, gamma-rays, nspo

The Taipei Times article [NSPO head eyeing 80% autonomy of satellite industry](https://www.taipeitimes.com/News/taiwan/archives/2021/10/21/2003766507) says:

> Following the six-satellite Formosat-7/COSMIC-2 constellation’s launch in 2019, weather observation satellite Triton is scheduled to be launched next year, Wu told a news conference in Taipei to mark the agency’s 30th anniversary.
>
> Meanwhile, the agency is working on the **Formosat-8 project**, which would comprise six remote-sensing satellites with a resolution of 0.7m each, Wu said, adding that its first satellite is set to be launched in 2023.

Gunter's space page [Formosat-8](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/formosat-8.htm) says:

> Some of the satellites will carry a secondary payload. **FORMOSAT-8B will carry a Gamma-ray Transients Monitor (GTM)**, which will be developed by the National Tsing Hua University.

Per http://www.astr.nthu.edu.tw/p/406-1336-187542,r3541.php?Lang=en:

> GTM was also selected for feasibility study **to fly on board a lunar-orbit spacecraft of NSPO, planned to launch in 2025.**

**Question:** What will Taiwan's [NSPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Space_Organization) put in orbit around the Moon in 2025? How will it get there? What will it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [June 2, 2021](https://www.taipeitimes.com/News/taiwan/archives/2021/06/02/2003758465), the Taipei Times reported that the [National Central University](https://www.ncu.edu.tw/en/news/show.php?num=1110) (NCU) was partnering with [HelioX](https://helioxcosmos.en.taiwantrade.com/news/heliox-the-first-cis-lunar-aerospace-company-in-taiwan-takes-a-giant-leap-to-the-moon-2377610.html) and other local businesses to develop a scientific payload to be part of an international mission to the moon in 2023.

> HelioX Cosmos, a space services supplier, is the official representative of Japanese firm Space BD, a designated service provider for the Japan Aerospace Exploration Agency.

The plan is to develop a lunar lander for launch during the fourth quarter of 2023.

The name of the lander's developer was being withheld due to a non disclosure agreement.

Since 2020, "the NSPO has commissioned local scientists to conduct feasibility studies for payloads that could be installed on a lunar orbiter. ... It would complete a mission definition for its space exploration program by 2025".

The story was also reported in April 2021 by [Indonesia News.Net](https://www.indonesianews.net/newsr/11894)

---

### Interesting Reading

[Taiwan to make lunar lander for NASA moon-mining mission](https://phys.org/news/2016-07-taiwan-lunar-lander-nasa-moon-mining.html), 2016

[TiSpace´s Hapith I rocket fails to launch for third time](https://spacewatch.global/2021/09/tispaces-hapith-i-rocket-fails-to-launch-for-third-time/),2021

[Southern Launch rules out using rocket that caught fire](https://www.innovationaus.com/southern-launch-rules-out-using-rocket-that-caught-fire/)